# Where can I buy a replacement DVD drive for my HP Laptop model dv6700?

Tags: dvd

Where can I buy a replacement DVD drive for my HP Laptop model dv6700?  Is this something I have to buy directly from HP or are there other companies that make and sell them?  Any tips for finding the best price are also greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!  I'm going to continue researching these questions right now!

Answer (score 1):

HP would be your safest bet. They'll have the exact specification of drive that will fit into your laptop.

However, if you take the old drive out you should be able to find a serial or model number printed somewhere. If you search for this, you *might* find a cheaper alternative supplier. Why? Well HP will be using standard parts, you just have to find out which one.

Another avenue might be to post a wanted ad on Freecycle or Craig's List (is this still going?). Someone might have the same model laptop that broken in some other way (screen, motherboard etc.) and they might be willing to let you have the DVD drive for little or no cost.